# column indexing in tidyverse, working for loop

Tags: for-loop, matrix, dplyr, tidyverse, data-manipulation

Hej,

I would like to translate one for loop into a tidyverse workflow, because I generally follow tidyverse approaches and like to use a piped workflow. I can archieve what I want easily using a for loop.

Here is a minimal reproducible example in which I identify the column where a 1 occurs for the first time (nr. of column) by each row. Then, I use this to index my matrix and set NA's in each column before the first 1.

```
# set seed
set.seed(10)

# create matrix of 0 and 1
matrix<-matrix(rbinom(100, 1, 0.4),nrow=10,ncol=10)

# get first column not being a zero (index)
first <- apply(matrix, 1, function(x) min(which(x !=0)))

# set all column before the indexed column to NA
for (i in 1:nrow(matrix)){
  
  if(first[i] > 1) matrix[i, 1:(first[i]-1)] <- NA
  
}

matrix
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of doing the same thing with `tidyverse`:

```
matrix |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(first = which.max(c_across(everything())),
         across(-first, ~ if_else(as.numeric(str_extract(cur_column(), "\\d+")) < first, NA, .))) |> # this is quite janky. If anyone knows a way of selecting column numbers within an across call, please comment with it
  ungroup() |> 
  select(-first)
```

This is quite janky though. If anyone knows a way of selecting column numbers within an across call, please comment with it! :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in `tidyverse`, I would recommend transforming the matrix from a "wide" format to a "long" one and perform whatever you want there. A "long" format is considered to be "tidy".

Here, the core concept is to use `cumsum` to return the cumulative sum per your original row. If it's zero, replace it with `NA`, otherwise keep it as it is.

```r
library(tidyverse)

as.data.frame(matrix) %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-rn) %>% 
  mutate(value = ifelse(cumsum(value) == 0, NA, value), .by = rn) %>% 
  pivot_wider() %>% 
  select(-rn)

# A tibble: 10 × 10
      V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1    NA     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
 2    NA    NA     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     1
 3    NA    NA     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
 4     1     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     1     0
 5    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     1     0     0     0
 6    NA    NA     1     1     0     0     1     0     0     1
 7    NA    NA     1     1     0     0     0     0     1     0
 8    NA    NA    NA     1     0     0     0     1     0     0
 9     1     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     1
10    NA     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
```